# Splitting a string in java with more than one split parameter

Tags: java, string

I am working with strings and had a quick question. I have a string of text I extracted from a file and now want to create a string array with each sentence of the text, I understand I could use `string.split(".");` for periods but how do I add question marks and exclamation marks. I tried `string.split("." + "!" + "?");` but that didn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `string.split("[.!?]")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string.split(".")` does not work as you expect it does...

```
String s = "Hello.world";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("."))); // outputs []
```

Split method takes a *regex*.

```
String s = "Hello.world";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\."))); // outputs [Hello, world]
```

The regex of `".!?"` says "any character followed by zero or more `!`" (which effectively is the same result as just `"."`)

If you want to split on individual characters, use a character class

`string.split("[.!?]")`

Comment: And since its a sentence if you want to retain the split character `(?<=[.!?])`